# I need help writing an if () then command

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to write a file that kills every task that runs. I know how to kill these tasks but I need help writing an ***if () then*** command. All I want to do is make it to where ***if the command prompt*** is closed ***then the computer logs off***. To also mention, I know how to do the log off command which is shutdown /l. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Or if there is not a way to do this maybe a way to relaunch the batch file without being triggered by a click. Or a way to make the batch file not be able to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to run this in the background:

```
@echo off
:loopme
start /WAIT "c:\path\to\batch.file.bat"
goto loopme
```

put that in the startup folder in the start menu... and... voila!

hope this helps! ~CSS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a monitor Batch file which checks if a PID of the main Batch file exists...
The main file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
title Main Batch File
set T=%TEMP%\sthUnique.tmp
wmic process where (Name="WMIC.exe" AND CommandLine LIKE "%%%TIME%%%") get ParentProcessId /value | find "ParentProcessId" >%T%
set /P A=<%T%
set PID=%A:~16%
echo %PID% > pid.pref
rem The rest of the file is down here...
```

That gets the current PID and stores it in `pid.pref`.
The monitor batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
title Monitor
start mainfile.bat
ping localhost -n 1 -w 2000 >NUL
< pid.pref (set /p pid=)
:loop
tasklist /fi "PID eq %pid%" |find ":" > nul
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
    shutdown.exe /s /t 00
    exit
)
goto loop
```

The monitor batch file checks if a process with the same PID exists, if not it shuts down the computer. Now, you could get unlucky if a process opens just after the main Batch file closes and Windows gives the new process the same PID, but this is highly unlikely.
By the way, start the monitor first, it will start the main file on it's own.

Note: I have **not** tested this.